# Are there any magic items in 5e that will cast Pass Without Trace?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, surprise

I've been looking for a way for my Assassin Rogue 12/War Domain Cleric 2 character to be able to cast Pass Without Trace, so they can more easily not abandon the party and still get surprise. Getting that surprise round is the goal, so if you have another way we can do it, that'd be great. Our party does not have a druid or thief rogue, so unfortunately we cannot use the Staff of the Woodlands, which would otherwise be perfect because, well:

> You can also use an action to cast the Pass without Trace spell from the staff without using any Charges.

Anyways, Does anyone know of a similar magic item that will allow us to cast pass without trace? Or an alternative way to gain surprise on our enemies other than stealthing into each room?

Comment: Do you have access to NPC spellcasting services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one other non-homebrew item, but you are not likely to come across it; the [Infiltrator’s Key](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/infiltrators-key).

> While holding the key, you can use an action to cast one of the following spells from it: alter self, invisibility, knock, or pass without trace. Once a spell has been cast using the key, it can’t be used to cast that spell again until the next dawn.

Unfortunately, it is a Legendary item so it would be hard to come by. Moreso, it only appears in the *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* supplement making it even more rare. It still requires attunement, but it can be with any class.

Comment: This looks perfect. Hunting down or purchasing a legendary item is going to be difficult, though. But not impossible! Do you know how to get a dormant key into the awakened or exalted state?

Comment: @Mister_Gaming3 The details on that process can be found in chapter 6 of *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to MivaScott's answer, a **Ring of Spell Storing** might serve your purpose.

**Ring of Spell Storing**

> This ring stores spells cast into it, holding them until the attuned wearer uses them. The ring can store up to 5 levels worth of spells at a time. **When found, it contains 1d6 - 1 levels of stored spells chosen by the DM.**
>
> Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the ring. If the ring can't hold the spell, the spell is expended without effect. The level of the slot used to cast the spell determines how much space it uses.
>
> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell. The spell cast from the ring is no longer stored in it, freeing up space.

Thus, your DM could create a Ring of Spell Storing with Pass Without Trace stored in it, allowing you to cast the spell. The ring can store a maximum of two Pass Without Trace spells and one other level one spell.

Should you need a recharge, your DM might allow an NPC in town to cast that spell for you to store.

Discuss with your DM

Comment: That seems like a potential option, and while I am a fan of the ring of spell storing, it can only hold 5 levels of spells and Pass Without Trace is a 2nd level spell, so it could only hold 2 of those at maximum capacity. And it requires attunement, which means someone else would have to attune to it to put the spell into it, no? meaning it would take a full day to get it refilled each time, assuming the spellcaster who agrees to help has 2 2nd level spell slots, otherwise it could take 2 days, and then I have to attune to it.

Comment: Attunment is not required for casting spells to store. It will store the spells of whoever casts into it. Only a user who is attuned can use the ring to cast the stored spells. Attunment doesn't require a full day either, merely a short rest. Ultimately, this is the cheapest non-homebrew option, I believe. As a DM I think this is also a very balanced way to give a spell but that's just me

Comment: Ah. thanks for the clarification. I'll see if I can hunt one of those down. And maybe a druid/ranger, too.

Comment: I mean, honestly even if I can get my hands on a magic item to cast Pass without Trace, I'll probably nab one of these at first chance simply because I have so few spell slots.